# Is there a way to prevent insertion of duplicate rows in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

I have an `ORC` Table. I populate it using the data from some other table as follows:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE orc_table_name SELECT * FROM other_table_name
```

Is there any way I can prevent inserting of duplicate entries into the ORC Table?

Answer (score 1):

you can use not in command See a general code below: it inserts records to the orc_table_name based on the fact that value1 from TABLE_1 was not inserted before.

```
INSERT INTO orc_table_name
  (Value1, Value2)
SELECT t1.Value1,
       t1.Value2
  FROM TABLE_1 t1
 WHERE t1.Value1 NOT IN (SELECT Value1 FROM orc_table_name)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO orc_table_name(field1,field2....fieldn)
select field1,field2... field(n-1),MIN(fieldn) as fieldn
from other_table_name
Group By field1,field2...field(n-1)
```

Comment: That will not avoid duplicate rows in `orc_table_name`... It only makes sure no duplicate rows are selected from `other_table_name`.